# Вывод под категорий товаров на странице категории

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть код который просто выводит все под категории на странице, а как его можно изменить, чтобы на странице категории выводились только ее под категории. К примеру есть категория посуда в нее входят дочерние элементы: тарелки, кружки. И категория Средства в нее входят: Фери, пемолюкс. Если зайти на страницу "Посуда" то сбоку мы увидим все дочерние категории который есть, а надо чтобы только тарелки и кружки. И проблема этого кода в том что он не выводит у дочерних элементов их под категории, то есть у тарелок есть еще категории: стекло, фарфор, но он их не выводит

```
 <div class="list-group">
       <?php
        $args = array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'hide_empty' => false,
         'parent'   => 0
        );
        $product_cat = get_terms( $args );
        foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat) {
        $child_args = array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'hide_empty' => false,
         'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
      );
       $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
        foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
       {
        echo '<a class="list-group-item" href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a>';
       }
     }
   ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Делайте по анологии

Таблица категорий:

```
CREATE  TABLE `categories` (
`id` INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`parent_id`  INT NOT NULL ,
`name`  VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY  ( `id` )
);
```

Выборка всех категорий

```
//Выбираем данные из БД
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  categories");
//Если в базе данных есть записи, формируем массив
if   (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $cats = array();
//В цикле формируем массив разделов, ключом будет id родительской категории, а также массив разделов, ключом будет id категории
    while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $cats_ID[$cat['id']][] = $cat;
        $cats[$cat['parent_id']][$cat['id']] =  $cat;
    }
}
```

Функция для построения дерева

```
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id,$only_parent = false){
    if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$parent_id])){
        $tree = '<ul>';
        if($only_parent==false){
            foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
                $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
                $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
                $tree .= '</li>';
            }
        }elseif(is_numeric($only_parent)){
            $cat = $cats[$parent_id][$only_parent];
            $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
        $tree .= '</ul>';
    }
    else return null;
    return $tree;
}
```

Вызов функции (вторим параметром передаете id категории, дочерние элементы которой нужно вывести (0 - все категории))

```
echo build_tree($cats,0);
```

[Источник](https://phpdes.com/php/postroenie-dereva-kategorijj-na-php-rekursiya/)